# What is acceptable set of values $E[ \max(X-10,0)]$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be random variable such that:

- $X \in \{0,1,2,... \}$
- $\Pr(X=0) = 0.8$
- $\Pr(X>0) = 0.2$
- $E(X|X>0)=100$

What can you say about $E[ \max(X-10,0)]$ (what is acceptable set of values $E[ \max(X-10,0)]$ ?

Of course, we have:

$$E[ \max(X-10,0)] = \sum_{k=11}^{\infty} k \Pr(X=k)$$

Furthermore using $E(X|X>0)=100$ we have: $E(X|X>0) = \frac{E(X)}{\Pr(X>0)}$ hence $E(X) = 20$.

Next we have $$E(X) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k \Pr(X=k) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k \Pr(X=k) = \sum_{k=1}^{10} k \Pr(X=k) + \sum_{k=11}^{\infty} k \Pr(X=k) = 20$$

The second element of this sum is this what I'm searching. What can I say about the first $\sum_{k=1}^{10} k \Pr(X=k)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random variable $Z = \max\{X-10,0\}$ can be written using the indicator function as

$$Z = (X-10)\cdot I_{\{X>10\}}$$

Then

$$E(Z) = E\Big(X\cdot I_{\{X>10\}}\Big) -10E\Big(I_{\{X>10\}}\Big) $$

$$=E\Big(X\cdot (1-I_{\{X\le10\}})\Big) - 10\Big(1-P(X\le 10)\Big)$$

$$=E(X) -E\Big(X\cdot I_{\{X\le10\}}\Big) - 10 +10\Big (0.8 + \sum_{k=1}^{10}\Pr(X=k)\Big)$$

The random variable $Y=X\cdot I_{\{X\le10\}}$ takes the values of $X$ for $X\le 10$ and the value $0$ if $X>10$. So
$$E\Big(X\cdot I_{\{X\le10\}}\Big) = \sum_{k=0}^{10} k \Pr(X=k) = \sum_{k=1}^{10} k \Pr(X=k)$$

Using also results in the question we arrive at

$$E(Z) = 20 - \sum_{k=1}^{10} k \Pr(X=k) - 10 +8 +10\sum_{k=1}^{10}\Pr(X=k) $$
$$=18 +\sum_{k=1}^{10}(10-k)\Pr(X=k) = 18 +\sum_{k=1}^{9}(10-k)\Pr(X=k)$$

Therefore, the minimum possible value of $E(Z)$ is $18$. As for an upper bound:
We have that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \Pr(X=k) =0.2 \Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{9} \Pr(X=k) \le 0.2$$

To obtain an upper bound we have to maximize over the probabilities the expression $\sum_{k=1}^{9}(10-k)\Pr(X=k)$ subject to the above inequality constraint. It is evident that the largest value this sum can possibly take is if we assign the value $0.2$ in $\Pr(X=1)$ in which case the value of the sum becomes $9\cdot 0.2 = 1.8$

Therefore $E(\max\{X-10,0\})$ ranges in $(18,\; 19.8)$

Intuitively, we should expect that $E(Z) = E(\max\{X-10,0\}) <  E(X)$.